# Custom functions in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

how would I implement custom functions in SQL?
Let's say I have a list of values and I want to transform those in a way where SQL doesn't supply a default function. E.g. look at every field's string, count the number of chars and add the sum of it to the end of each string.

In a programming language this is easy, e.g. save the field's string in a variable A, loop through the string char by char and increasing a counter by one each time, adding the counter to variable A.

But how would I do this in SQL? Can I implement EVERY function solely with the means of SQL, or do I need to use a common programming language like Java, or something like PL/SQL for that?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? All the major RDBMSes have the ability to create custom functions to achieve your example.

Comment: PostgreSQL. Yes, but how do those custom functions look like? Are they implemented in pure SQL syntax or do I need to use any programming language to achieve this? I try to find out, if I can do EVERY MANIPULATION to my data with SQL as I could with a common programming language? Or if SQL's strength primarily lies in FILTERING?

Comment: Sounds like a custom aggregate function. I think postgres lets you make those.

Comment: In Postgres you can implement functions in SQL, PL/pgSQL, Perl, Python and several other languages http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html